# XHR failed loading: POST in cordova

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm using cordova to buid a mobile app with simple login form. The problem is whenever I enter the wrong username and password I'm able to get the response from the server as INVALID INFORMATION in XML.
But when I enter the valid username and Password I'm getting the log in console as ***XHR failed loading: POST***.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://remoteServerIP/login.do", 
            data:{
                password:$('#pass').val(),
                method:"login",
                userName:$('#uname').val(),
                cType:"LOGIN"
                },
            type:'post',
            dataType: 'xml',
            async: true,
            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(result){


                    alert("Data: "+result.data);

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

            alert("msg: "+thrownError.message+" , status: "+xhr.status);
            }
    });
    });
});
```

The config.xml:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.MyApp.App" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name = "SplashScreen" value = "screen" />
    <preference name = "SplashScreenDelay" value = "4000" />
    <preference name = "SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value = "true" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>


    <name>DikshaTouch</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <!-- <access origin="*" /> -->
    <access origin="http://remoteServerIP" subdomain="true" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon src="www/img/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icon.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icon.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icon.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>`
```

Comment: any console errors 404, 500?

Comment: no, only XHR failed loading when I enter a valid data. Thanks for Replying

Comment: i don't see any console.log in your ajax request so this error is from another code

Comment: @AkshayPalekar could you display your config.xml? Also did you taken care of whitelisting?

Comment: @Gandhi Ya sure ill show the config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved the problem. 
The problem was I was making the asynchronous call thats why its was debug log as ***XHR failed loading: POST*** when i was sending the vaild data to the server.
I just changed **async:true** to **async:false**

Here is my altered code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://remoteServerIP/login.do", 
            data:{
                password:$('#pass').val(),
                method:"login",
                userName:$('#uname').val(),
                cType:"LOGIN"
                },
            type:'post',
            dataType: 'xml',
            async: false,
            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(result){


                    alert("Data: "+result.data);

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

            alert("msg: "+thrownError.message+" , status: "+xhr.status);
            }
    });
    });
});
```

Now I'm getting the required response from the server..

Comment: async false is defeating the purposing of AJAX basically

Comment: Ya It is deprecated , but I'm  getting the response from the server